# What does $\langle -z|$ mean in this expression $\langle -z|\rho|z\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, density-operator, wigner-transform

In some formulas of the Wigner function, there is an expression $\langle -z|\rho|z\rangle$ where $|z\rangle$ represents a coherent state. I don't understand what $\langle - z|$ means. Some other formulas are written in terms of $Tr(\rho \hat{A})$ which is fine because by using $Tr(\rho \hat{A})=\langle \psi|\hat{A}|\psi\rangle$ (where $\rho=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$), I can solve it. However, I do not get the $-z$ in $\langle -z|\rho|z\rangle$ representation. I do not want anyone to solve this for me. Just give me an idea what $\langle-z|$ means? Moreover, I want to solve derivations for wigner functions by myself but unfortunately, I am unfamiliar with some basic points. The books I've been reading are "Quantum Optics" by G.S. Agarwal and "Introductory Quantum Optics" by Peter L. Knight and Christopher C. Gerry. Can someone guide me some other books which start from basics and which will help me improve me in solving derivations? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with "solve"?

Comment: I don't understand the term $\langle-z|$ here. If I can understand it, I'll be able to solve it. I am not asking for someone to solve this for me.

Comment: It is treated with the aid of the eigen-equation $\hat{z}|z\rangle=|z\rangle z$. It means that $\langle -z|\hat{z} = -z\langle -z|$. Provided that $\hat{\rho}$ is expressed in terms of $\hat{z}$, one can solve the expression.

Comment: @flippiefanus Thank you:) Here $|z\rangle$  is a coherent state. For a coherent state $|\alpha\rangle$, we know that $\hat{a}|\alpha\rangle= \alpha |\alpha\rangle$. Does this imply $\hat{a}|-\alpha\rangle=- \alpha |-\alpha\rangle$?

Comment: Yes, it does… .

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thank you:)

Comment: Delete your question, then?